# Which services are enabled by default in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

After upgrade to ubuntu desktop 13.04 i have these services enabled (i reviewed with rcconf):

```
│ [*] acpi-support

│ [*] brltty Braille terminal driver

│ [*] grub-common Record successful boot for GRUB

│ [*] kerneloops Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures

│ [*] ondemand Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand" 

│ [*] pppd-dns Restore resolv.conf if the system crashed.

│ [*] rsync fast remote file copy program daemon

│ [*] sudo Provide limited super user privileges to specific users

│ [*] x11-common

| [ ] acpid

│ [ ] alsa-restore

│ [ ] alsa-store

│ [ ] anacron 

│ [ ] apparmor AppArmor initialization

│ [ ] apport 

│ [ ] avahi-cups-reload

│ [ ] avahi-daemon

│ [ ] bluetooth

│ [ ] console-font

│ [ ] console-setup

│ [ ] cron 

│ [ ] cups 

│ [ ] cups-browsed

│ [ ] dbus 

│ [ ] dmesg

│ [ ] failsafe-x

│ [ ] friendly-recovery

| [ ] hostname 

│ [ ] hwclock

│ [ ] hwclock-save 
│ [ ] irqbalance

│ [ ] kmod

│ [ ] lightdm

│ [ ] modemmanager

│ [ ] network-interface

│ [ ] network-interface-container

│ [ ] network-interface-security 

│ [ ] network-manager

│ [ ] plymouth

│ [ ] plymouth-log

│ [ ] plymouth-splash

│ [ ] plymouth-stop

│ [ ] plymouth-upstart-bridge

│ [ ] procps 

│ [ ] pulseaudio

│ [ ] resolvconf 

│ [ ] rfkill-restore 

│ [ ] rfkill-store

│ [ ] rsyslog 

│ [ ] saned SANE network scanner server

│ [ ] setvtrgb

[ ] speech-dispatcher Speech Dispatcher

│ [ ] udev 

│ [ ] udev-fallback-graphics

│ [ ] udev-finish

│ [ ] udevmonitor

│ [ ] udevtrigger

│ [ ] ufw 

│ [ ] whoopsie
```

My question is, Which services are enabled by default in Ubuntu 13.04?

Maybe some body can take a look in a fresh 13.04 installation with rcconf utility (rcconf is not installed by default)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 13.04 is still not released, and is thus off-topic per the FAQ http://askubuntu.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you upgraded from a previous installation. This means that the default services will vary. In my case I would show Apache and Mysql installed additionally to the ones you pointed out. In other users they would show others.

From a fresh install it would certainly be the same as you but could change if a special hardware device needs an additional service to be able to work correctly.

For what I could compare to your list, I would say we have the same except that I have Apache, MySQL and a couple of more related to servers.